# SUM($row["Rating"]) and then divide by Count(ID_Jogo) Where tb_jogo.ID_Jogo=$row[ID_Jogo"], print it as "Rating here" for 6 different products

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make it so I can SUM the ratings(1-5 stars) of a certain product and then divide the ammount of votes of that same product (count), printing it along with the products and their respective ratings, I've tried over and over to make it work, I'm self taught, and I can't find a way to do this.
Could I get some help?
What I want to replace is the "Rating here" portion.
The rating table goes as: ID_Rating(key), ID_Jogo (foreign key for the product), ID_User (for tracking who already has voted, foreign key), Rating(1-5)
Thanks!

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pap";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `tb_jogo` ORDER BY `ID_Jogo` DESC LIMIT 6";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row["Preco"]==0 || $row["Preco"]==NULL || $row["Preco"]=='' || $row["Preco"]==' '){
        $preco='Gratuito';
    }else $preco=$row["Preco"].'€';
    echo "
        <div class='col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6'>
                   <div class='product__item'>
                       <div class='product__sidebar__view__item set-bg mix day years'data-setbg='jogos/".$row["Imagem"]."'>
                          <div class='ep'>"Rating here" <i class='fa fa-star' aria-hidden='true'</i></div>
                            <div class='view'><i class='fa fa-download'></i> ".$row["Vendas"]."</div>
                              <h5><a href='detalhes-jogo.php?ID_Jogo=".$row["ID_Jogo"]."'>".$row["Nome"]."</a></h5>
</div>
           <div class='product__item__text'>
                                <ul><li style='background: #851BEC'>".$preco."</li>
                                    <li style='background: #3d3d3d'>".$row["Tags"]."</li>
                </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>";
                            }
                        }
?>
```

I tried to make another sql query in seperate, but that didn't seem to work

Comment: You have to do it using SQL Query. It is inefficient to retrieve all the rows and do the calculation.

Comment: How would I go about that exactly?

Comment: Search for an introduction to the SQL `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I still don't see the solution to this, hm

Answer (score 0):

It is inefficient to retrieve all the rows and do the calculation, therefore you have to do this using SQL Query.

Below query will group the Products by product ID(ID_Jogo) and then we add all the rating of that Product(`SUM(Rating)`) and then divide it by the number of rows(`COUNT(*)`) to get the rating. `AS ProductRating` statement just renames the retrieved column. So that you can access it using the name `ProductRating` (Ex: `$row["ProductRating"]`)

```
SELECT ID_Jogo, SUM(Rating)/COUNT(*) AS Rating FROM `tb_jogo` GROUP BY ID_Jogo;
```

Sample Table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tb_jogo;
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
| ID_Rating | ID_Jogo | ID_User | Rating |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
|         1 |       1 |       1 |      4 |
|         2 |       1 |       2 |      4 |
|         3 |       1 |       3 |      5 |
|         4 |       1 |       4 |      4 |
|         5 |       2 |       1 |      4 |
|         6 |       2 |       2 |      4 |
|         7 |       2 |       3 |      4 |
|         8 |       1 |       5 |      4 |
+-----------+---------+---------+--------+
```

Running the above SQL Query will return following result:

```
mysql> SELECT ID_Jogo, SUM(Rating)/COUNT(*) AS Rating FROM `tb_jogo` GROUP BY ID_Jogo;
+---------+--------+
| ID_Jogo | Rating |
+---------+--------+
|       1 | 4.2000 |
|       2 | 4.0000 |
+---------+--------+
```

If you want to round the decimal places, you could use `ROUND` function in SQL or you can use PHP too. This is how you can round it to 1 decimal place using SQL Query.

```
mysql> SELECT ID_Jogo, ROUND(SUM(Rating)/COUNT(*), 1) AS Rating FROM `tb_jogo` GROUP BY ID_Jogo;
+---------+--------+
| ID_Jogo | Rating |
+---------+--------+
|       1 |    4.2 |
|       2 |    4.0 |
+---------+--------+
```